# Expand image to left and right on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to animate an image to left and right on mouseover and on mouseout it will bring back to previous state.

For eg if the original width of the image is 120 px then on page load it will show 100 px and on mouseover it will expand to left and right.So it will be 10px more to left and 10px more to right.

```
<img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1742172/2000/v/110/depositphotos_20007761-Old-scroll-banner-cartoon.jpg" id="expandimg" />
```

**Demo**  http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/9FtBY/5/

But now it is expanding only in right side. Please any suggestion would be great.

Just discovered that there is something called clip in css3?

Comment: how about that: http://jsfiddle.net/9FtBY/7/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, basically your code is correct. The animation looks like it would expand to the right, because the image is aligned left.

If you wrapped it up in a div and let that have centered align, it would look "good".

```
<div class="wrapper"><img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1742172/2000/v/110/depositphotos_20007761-Old-scroll-banner-cartoon.jpg" id="expandimg" /></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GVdmF/

---

"Good" in quotation marks, because the image gets stretched. You'd better go with a solution which uses background-images. If you hold on a second, I might see what I can do.

---

Edit: Here we go again: http://jsfiddle.net/GVdmF/2/

- I split up your pictures in 3 parts: left.png, center.png and right.png.
- I added center.png to the div
- I added the pseudo-classes :before and :after, made them block elements and added height/widht and also the corresponding background-images left.png and right.png

Your JS pretty much stayed the same. Hope this helped.

Comment: Hi Boris,that's brilliant.Actually splitting up the image in 3 parts makes sense now and that is what I thought at the first place.What I am after now is to keep the center.png in it's place but the left and right.png needs moving in both side.is that possible.Also just wondering if the same thing can be achieved without splitting the image?I mean when the page loads the 10px from both side will be hidden and when you mouseover the mid part then both side will be revealed animatedly..Thanks once again.

Comment: Updated:http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/JS6Rb/6/ but only issue is that the transition is not so smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I would use absolute positioning relative to a parent container in combination with `max-width` and `max-height` and reseting them to `none` on hover:

```
.img:hover img {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: none;
    max-height: none;
    left: -25%;
    top: -25%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xv9dh/

UPD. didn't see your demo, so probably my answer is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with pure CSS, in two ways (at least!):

http://jsfiddle.net/9FtBY/10/

```
#expandimg {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
}

#expandimg:hover {
    width: 120px;
    margin-left: 0px;    
}
```

Or second one, with `position: absolute;`

http://jsfiddle.net/9FtBY/7/

```
#expandimg {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
}

#expandimg:hover {
    width: 120px;
    left: 0px;    
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc,That's brilliant.One slight change in the plan.If you please read my last comment to Boris's post.Actually When the page loads for the first time the extreme left and right parts shouldn't be shown and when you mouseover the center.png then the left and right part will be displayed animatedly.So basically the mid part will be constant.I am wondering if it can be achieved by not splitting the image into 3 parts and just only using css?For eg 10px from both side will be hidden and when you mouseover the image ,both sides will be displayed animatedly.Thanks

Comment: Updated:http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/JS6Rb/6/ but only issue is that the transition is not so smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple `animation` concept,

If you are going `animate` an element by incrementing its `width`, and you need it to be displayed like a stretching effect. just use this,

```
Left = Left - (incrementedWidth/2)
```

To revert it,

```
Left = Left + (incrementedWidth/2)
```

**CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#expandimg").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            //Decrement Left in pixel = 20/2 [20 increment in width]
            left: "-=10", 
            width: '120px'
        }, "fast"); 
    });
    $("#expandimg").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            //Increment Left in pixel = 20/2 [20 decrement in width]
            width: '100px',
            left: "+=10"
        }, "fast"); 
    });
});
```

[Note: If you are using property `left`, then you must have set a position like `absolute`, in order to access it.]

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9FtBY/11/)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Prabhu for your help.There is a slight change on the plan and I am after something where on page load 10px from both side will be hidden and when you mouseover the center part of the image, then the both sides will be displayed animated(like now).I think there is a couple of way to do this.1)Splitting the image in 3 parts 2)using some kind of padding/margin in both sides(on page load).I prefer the second method but not sure where to implement the padding or margin.Please read my last comment to the above posts.Many thanks.:)

Comment: Updated:http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/JS6Rb/6/ but only issue is that the transition is not so smooth.